# How is date and time stored in the DateTime class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, datetime

I've looked up the DateTime class in the PHP manual page, and I saw that the class has no properties at all. So how is date and time stored inside a DateTime object? How does the __construct() or the setDate() method work, since there's no properties to set?

Comment: It has no _public_ properties you are allowed to see ;)

Comment: Probably in private properties. They don't seem to be listed on the php.net manual

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really want to know, you can always check read the source code:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c

It seems that `DateTime` contains the UNIX time, and the timezone. Which logically should be enough to handle the time correctly.  Now I didn't read the 4258 lines, and I suggest you don't read it (unless it's out of curiosity) and use public methods instead.

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu. I thought DataTime was just like a custom class created from PHP syntax and such. I never thought it would be this complicated.